# Javascript only works in Safari with alert

Tags: javascript, safari, alert

I am a newbie to javascript and am having trouble getting my script to work in Safari. I have done numerous google searches to find a solution, but haven't found anything that worked.

I have an HTML page that uses javascript to load an swf and a caption from two separate arrays. There is a next button that will load another SWF and a new caption upon being clicked. It works perfectly in IE and Firefox, but in Safari the new SWF does not display. In the Safari debugger it shows the correct new SWF file name, but displays the original SWF on screen. The only way I have gotten it to work is if I have an alert after the code. I have tried adjusting the order of events in my function, but that has not solved anything.

Any ideas? (I apologize if I've provided too much code, I just want to give you the full picture.)

Javascript (located in the header):

```
var swfFrame=new Array();
swfFrame[0]='frame_01.swf';
swfFrame[1]='frame_02.swf';
swfFrame[2]='frame_03.swf';

var paragraphTxt=new Array();
paragraphTxt[0]='caption 1';
paragraphTxt[1]='caption 2';
paragraphTxt[2]='caption 3';

function nextFrame(x){
i = i+x;
if(i>=swfFrame.length){
    i=i-1;
    window.open('quiz.html');
}else{
document.getElementById("framenum").innerHTML = (i+1) + " of " + swfFrame.length;
document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = paragraphTxt[i];
// IE
document.getElementById("flashPlayer").movie = "swf/" + swfFrame[i];
// FIREFOX et al
<!--[if !IE]>-->
document.getElementById("flashPlayer").data = "swf/" + swfFrame[i];
<!--[endif}-->
//  ALERT (doesn't work in Safari if alert is off)
alert(document.getElementById("flashPlayer").data);
}
if(i>0){
    document.getElementById("button_Bck").style.visibility = "visible";
}else{
    hideBack();
}
}

function hideBack(){
document.getElementById("button_Bck").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

Code for button used to advance to the next swf:

```
<a href="javascript://" onclick="nextFrame(1)"><div id="button_Nxt"><div id="buttonText">Next</div></div></a>
```

Comment: Are you getting any javascript errors or warnings?

Comment: No errors or warnings, it just doesn't load in the new swf.

Answer (score 0):

@rlane423: I don't think you can actually use conditional comments like that within a script block.

Try --

```
    /* preceding code omitted for brevity */

    var isIE = false; // set to false by default
</script>

<!--[if IE]>
<script type="text/javascript">
    isIE = true;
</script>
<![endif]-->

<script type="text/javascript">
     if (isIE) {
         // IE
         document.getElementById("flashPlayer").movie = "swf/" + swfFrame[i];
     } else {
         // FIREFOX et al
         document.getElementById("flashPlayer").data = "swf/" + swfFrame[i];
     }

     /* rest of script omitted for brevity */
</script>
```

Comment: I had not had any problems doing it the way I posted. I tried it this way and it still didn't work in Safari. But it also stopped working in Firefox. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @rlane423: Is this available on-line anywhere?

Comment: It is on my company's password protected development site, which I cannot give access to. A coworker helped me implement this code and now it works in Firefox again, but still not in Safari.

Comment: @rlane423: I think the problem is that Safari also uses `.movie` and not `.data`. I'm going to look later to see if I can't find a good way to detect Safari in JavaScript to then serve it the same string as you feed IE.

Comment: When I check the code in Safari's web inspector it shows that it's using data.

Answer (score 0):

Is your array index of i actually making it to the third index?

If you are calling your function nextFrame(1) each time... are you only passing the number 1 into the function each time you call the function or do you have 3 different function calls with

nextFrame(1)
nextFrame(2)
nextFrame(3)

also, you have not declared i as in var i = 0; I would do this ... for these purposes your code would be a lot lighter if you were to declare i as global outside of your nextFrame function and then increment it by 1 every time the nextframe() function is called. And then load in the movie you want based on the global i.

```
var i = 0;
function nextFrame(){
    loadSwf[i];
    i++;
}
```

then call the function with

```
onclick="nextFrame()"
```

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally left that out of the code I posted. I have var i=0; declared above my arrays. Each time I call the function it is using "nextFrame(1)". I also have a back button, so that uses "nextFrame(-1)".

Comment: So can you tell us if you are in fact making it to the third index of your array?

Comment: Yes, it goes all the way through the array.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is due to the fact that flash runs in a separate thread from javascript. When you use an alert for debugging and your page includes flash you can run into these sorts of heisenbugs. In the absence of flash, everything on your page, including javascript, will block during an alert. Flash on the other hand runs on a separate thread and does not block for alerts.

This example illustrates what I am talking about:

```
<object width="480" height="390"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/oHg5SJYRHA0?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/oHg5SJYRHA0?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="480" height="390"></embed></object>
<a href="javascript:alert('hello'); return false;">Click me!</a>
```

Start the movie and then click the link - the video will not stop playing while the alert is up.

The easiest fix for this is probably to wrap the code after the alert statement in a setTimeout function with a short delay:

```
setTimeout(function() { ... }, 50);
```

A better fix would be to register an event with the flash movie or poll it until it's ready to be updated.

Comment: I have tried putting setTimeout within the button onClick and that didn't seem to have any affect. I also tried putting it within my function where the flash is being swapped and that didn't work either.

Comment: You tried putting everything after the alert in a timeout? Did you try increasing the timeout delay?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution that works. It may be a complete hack, but it's working in all the browsers I need it to.

First I changed the way I was detecting IE, as suggested by @stealthyninja. Then I decided to try entirely reloading the flash instead of just swapping the file name of the swf. The first flash is being loaded using the swfobject.js dynamic publishing method. So I am reloading the subsequent frames the same way. I wanted to use innerHTML for this, but it didn't like me trying to put javascript in it. So I added an empty javascript block within the div of the flash content and used innerHTML to load the swfobject call within that. (Hopefully this makes sense and isn't a totally backwards way of doing it.) Code is below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var isIE =false;
</script>

<!--[if IE]>
<script type="text/javascript">
    isIE = true;
</script>
<![endif]-->

<script type="text/javascript">
    var flashvars = {};
    var params = {};
    params.play = "true";
    params.loop = "false";
    params.menu = "false";
    params.quality = "best";
    params.wmode = "window";
    params.bgcolor = "#FFFFFF";
    params.allowscriptaccess = "sameDomain";
    var attributes = {};
    attributes.align = "middle";
    swfobject.embedSWF("swf/frame_01.swf", "flashPlayer", "100%", "100%", "9.0.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes);

var i=0;
var swfFrame=new Array();
    swfFrame[0]='frame_01.swf';
    swfFrame[1]='frame_02.swf';
    swfFrame[2]='frame_03.swf';

var paragraphTxt=new Array();
    paragraphTxt[0]='caption 1';
    paragraphTxt[1]='caption 2';
    paragraphTxt[2]='caption 3';

function nextFrame(x){
i = i+x;
//alert("i+x = " + (i));
if(i>=swfFrame.length){
    i=i-1;
    window.open('quiz.html');
}else{
    document.getElementById("framenum").innerHTML = (i+1) + " of " + swfFrame.length;
    document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = paragraphTxt[i];
    if(isIE){
        // IE
        document.getElementById("flashPlayer").movie = "swf/" + swfFrame[i];
    }else{
        document.getElementById("newScript").innerHTML = swfobject.embedSWF("swf/" + swfFrame[i],"flashPlayer","100%","100%","9.0.0",false,flashvars,params,attributes);
    }
}
if(i>0){
    document.getElementById("button_Bck").style.visibility = "visible";
}else{
    hideBack();
}
}
```

Div location of Flash content with newly added javascript block:

```
<div id="flash">
    <script type="text/javascript" id="newScript">
    </script>
        <div id="flashPlayer">
        <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
            <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
        </a>
        </div>
</div>
```